# How to add basic authentication to nswag studio generated .net6 client?

Tags: c#, swagger, basic-authentication, swagger-codegen, nswag

I don't understand what should I have to do to add basic authentication to calls performed by the generated code

I've tried to implement the `PrepareRequest()` methods like this, but I always get 401 as response

```
partial void PrepareRequest(HttpClient client, HttpRequestMessage request, string url)
{
    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{_settings.Username}:{_settings.Password}");
    request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
}

partial void PrepareRequest(HttpClient client, HttpRequestMessage request, StringBuilder urlBuilder)
{
    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{_settings.Username}:{_settings.Password}");
    request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));    
 }
```

I didn't find any documentation about that and I'm pretty lost